# How to inflate two custom layout (one is superclass and the other is subclass) with the same xml config

Tags: android

I have a custom layout class

```
public class LayoutA extends FrameLayout
{
 initialize()
  {
    someMethod();
  }

 someMethod()
  {
  }
...
}
```

and layout.xml accordingly

```
<mypkg.LayoutA   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    .... >
    ....
</mypkg.LayoutA>
```

Now I want to have a subclass LayoutB extends LayoutA, with exact the same xml configuration but override the `someMethod()`. Can I inflate LayoutB with the same layout.xml? Or any other solution I can call someMethod from LayoutB during runtime?

I've tried

```
<mypkg.LayoutB   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        .... >
        <include layout="@layout/LayoutA" />
    </mypkg.LayoutB>
```

but doesn't work

PS. there are some constraints...
1. better without changing LayoutA and layout.xml
2. no copy paste layout.xml to another file

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can include layout b inside layout A some thing like this, in xml of layout A

```
 <include
    layout="@layout/layout_b"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

if you want to hide this programatically

keep the include part inside a `Linearlayout` and make its visibility `gone`

Answer (score 0):

[image]You can take `LinearLayout` inside LayoutB  like below:

```
<mypkg.LayoutB   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        .... >
<Linearlayout />
</mypkg.LayoutB>
```

And When your somemethod() invoked in then you inflate LayoutA dynamically and add into LinearLayout which we have in LayoutB .

Here I Added layout_a  , layout_b And Activity LayoutB

layout_b:XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="LAYOUT B"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/add_layout_a"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

layout_a:XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="LAYOUT A"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Activity  :LayoutB

```
    package com.cj.myapplication;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;

    /**
     * Created by CHETAN on 2/10/2017.
     */

    public class LayoutA extends Activity {
        LinearLayout linearLayout;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.layout_b);
            initView();
        }
            private void initView(){
            linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.add_layout_a);
            //Below Dynamically inflate layout_a.xml and Add into  linearLayout of layout_b,xml          
            final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)     getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            LinearLayout LayoutA= (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_a, null);
            linearLayout.addView(LayoutA);

        }
    }
```

Comment: would that become LayoutB contents LayoutA, instead of having the same layout configuration? And could you please show in code how to inflate LayoutA and add to LinearLayout. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of way to combine custom layout to each other.

But the most common approach - **is to extend one of the built-in layouts and inflate custom layout during initialization**

By doing this, whenever we need to use our newly created custom view, the only thing we need to do is to add our view to the main layout like any other default views like you did it in your code.

But doing this will create extra hierarchy of views and it will create problem when we have more number of views and complex layouts, which will going to hit performance.

**So One of the possible ways to reduce number of layouts in our case is to merge our actual card's content into parent view.**

So for this we can use **merge** tag.

The last approach to reduce the number of layouts is to use **include** tag.
But by using this approach there are chances of loosing control over the underlaying layout of your views.

***So I prefer merge approach.***

There are some links which will explain this approach in detail. 
PLease have a look on the below links:

http://trickyandroid.com/protip-inflating-layout-for-your-custom-view/

https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/understanding-androids-layoutinflater-inflate/

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it this is what the dynamic binding means.

Simply create class A write both the method separate for parsing xml and for someMethods check the code here

```
public class LayoutA extends FrameLayout {
    public LayoutA(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initView();
        someMethod();
    }

    public LayoutA(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initView();
        someMethod();
    }

    public LayoutA(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initView();
        someMethod();
    }

    private void initView() {
        //Parse Your view here
    }


    protected void someMethod() {
        Log.e("", "Layout A");
    }
}
```

Override the someMethods in B 
whenever you'll request object of B it will always call class B method first which means your someMethod will override in B while view is same as you using in A.

```
public class LayoutB extends LayoutA {
    public LayoutB(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public LayoutB(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public LayoutB(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void someMethod() {
        //super.someMethod();

        Log.e("", "Layout B");
    }
}
```